# How to get memory usage AND SWAP space usage?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management, metrics

I am running a script in python that uses the TensorFlow API that requires memory beyond RAM and opts into swap space. Is there a way to monitor both for metrics purposes? I am trying to log additional data with the script, so I can avoid having metrics in different files.

As additional info, I am on Linux Ubuntu 16.04. Python 3.6.7 Tensorflow 1.11

Comment: There are MANY options (e.g., `free` and `top`). However, this question is off topic on SO.

Comment: Would be great to know why its off-topic. also search results for free are top general link. Perhaps links?